# Comparison with unicode string in if-condition (python)

Tags: python, if-statement, unicode-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python '==' vs 'is' comparing strings, 'is' fails sometimes, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why)

I am going to skip the part where i tell you how i tested my code and jump straight to the problem.

Python seems to be having some problem matching split of a unicode string to another inline unicode string in an if statement.

```
>>>zone = u'domain.com.'
>>>zone[-1:]
u'.'

>>>u'.' is u'.' #works fine
True
>>> z[-1:] == u'.' #works fine
True
>>> zone[-1:] is u'.' # FAILS !
False
```

here is my actual code snippet

```
>>>if zone[-1:] is not u'.':
>>>    #this line will always run !
```

if i change 'is not' to != the code works fine !

**Does anyone know why "is" caused the comparison to fail ?**

Comment: `is` compares identity, not equality.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150765/a-question-regarding-string-instance-uniqueness-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165688/is-this-a-bug-variables-are-identical-references-to-the-same-string-in-this-exam, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs to name but three.

Comment: @MartijnPieters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165688/is-this-a-bug-variables-are-identical-references-to-the-same-string-in-this-exam   this almost nails it i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because strings are objects in Python --- when you slice a string, you create a new one.

It's slightly more complicated than that, but that's the gist of it.

Solution: use `==` and `!=` instead of `is` and `is not`.